# Relabling of lables?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I'm facing an issue, where I need to "relable" lables.

I'm working on a mechanismn to run over a part of tex-file twice with two different parameters, in order to write out different parts of the text. By using \input with a variable set before. In the final PDF both arrangements should printed one after each other.

The mechanism works like this:

```
...
\DefCurrentLanguage{DE}
\input{content.tex}
\DefCurrentLanguage{EN}
\input{content.tex}
...
```

This creates me some problems, when I'm using labels. See here a simplified version (without \input, but with clear text)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\begin{document}

% Usually this is input my \input{myfile.txt} with the first option
\chapter{GERMAN}
\etocsettocstyle{\section*{Inhalt}}{}
\etocsettocdepth.toc{subsection}
\localtableofcontents
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{Eins}
Referenz auf zwei: \ref{mylabel}
\subsection{Ein.Eins}
\section{Zwei}\label{mylabel}


% Usually this is input my \input{myfile.txt} with the second option
\chapter{ENGLISH}
\etocsettocstyle{\section*{Content}}{}
\etocsettocdepth.toc{subsection}
\localtableofcontents
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{One}
Refenence to two: \ref{mylabel}
\subsection{One.One}
\section{Two}\label{mylabel}
\end{document}
```

I need something to rename the label mylabel to DE.mylabel in the first case and EN.mylabel in the second case.

I guess I somehow need to create an individual \label and \ref command? Any hint?
Using this as is, leads of course to multiple defined labels

Georg

Comment: How are you getting`\chapter{\lang}`?  Couldn't you also do `\label{\lang mylabel}`?

Comment: ok... that one was really simple.... thanks a lot..... sorry

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Teepeemm:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\begin{document}

% Usually this is input my \input{myfile.txt} with the first option
\def\lang {DE}
\chapter{GERMAN}
\etocsettocstyle{\section*{Inhalt}}{}
\etocsettocdepth.toc{subsection}
\localtableofcontents
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{Eins}
Referenz auf zwei: \ref{\lang mylabel}
\subsection{Ein.Eins}
\section{Zwei}\label{\lang mylabel}


% Usually this is input my \input{myfile.txt} with the second option
\def\lang {EN}
\chapter{ENGLISH}
\etocsettocstyle{\section*{Content}}{}
\etocsettocdepth.toc{subsection}
\localtableofcontents
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{One}
Refenence to two: \ref{\lang mylabel}
\subsection{One.One}
\section{Two}\label{\lang mylabel}
\end{document}
```